# Написание запроса, связывающего несколько таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть несколько связанных таблиц. В одной из них довольно большое количество записей (порядка 2млн). Необходимо написать запрос, выбирающий конкретные записи в определенный период.

База данных `MariaDB 10.8.3`

Таблицы (опущу неважные поля):

```
1. events (id, group_id, client_id, work_id, date) - занятия
2. works (id, schedule_id) - работы в расписании
3. schedules (id, user_id) - расписания
4. users (id, department) - Преподаватели
5. groups (id) - Учебные группы
6. clients (id, last_name, first_name, middle_name, birthdate) - Студенты
7. client_group (client_id, group_id) - Студенты в группе
```

Внешние ключи по всем id настроены. Необходимо выбрать всех студентов `(clients)`, у которых были занятия в определенный период `(events.date)` в определенном учебном корпусе `(users.department)`.
Занятия могут быть как в составе группы (тогда выбираются студенты, находящиеся в тех группах, id которых указаны в `events.group_id`), так и индивидуальные (в этом случае выбираются те клиенты, id которых указаны в `events.client_id`).

Я составил такой запрос:

```
select distinct clients.id, clients.last_name, clients.first_name, clients.middle_name, clients.birthdate
from clients
  join events on clients.id = events.client_id
  join works on events.work_id = works.id
  join schedules on works.schedule_id = schedules.id
  join users on schedules.user_id = users.id
where users.department = 98
  and events.client_id is not null
  and events.date between '2022-09-01' and '2022-11-14'

union

select distinct clients.id, clients.last_name, clients.first_name, clients.middle_name, clients.birthdate
from clients
  join client_group on clients.id = client_group.client_id
  join events on client_group.group_id = events.group_id
  join works on events.work_id = works.id
  join schedules on works.schedule_id = schedules.id
  join users on schedules.user_id = users.id
where users.department = 98
  and events.group_id is not null
  and events.date between '2022-09-01' and '2022-11-28'
order by last_name, first_name

limit 50 offset 0
```

Такой запрос у меня занимает порядка 2 минут. Я подозреваю, что это может быть либо из-за объединения двух запросов uniun-ом (хотя по отдельности они также долго выполняются, в районе минуты), либо из-за неверных индексов.

Индексы у меня такие:

```
clients_name_index (last_name(20), first_name(20), middle_name(20), birthdate)

client_group_client_id_group_id_index (client_id, group_id)
client_group_client_id_foreign (client_id)
client_group_group_id_foreign (group_id)

users_department_index (department)

schedules_user_id_foreign (user_id)

works_schedule_id_foreign (schedule_id)

events_date_index (date)
events_client_id_foreign (client_id)
events_group_id_foreign (group_id)
events_work_id_foreign (work_id)
```

Можно ли как-то переписать данный запрос, чтобы ускорить его выполнение?
Количество записей в таблицах:
`events` ~ 2 млн
`clients` ~ 300 000
`groups` ~ 80 000
Общий объём БД ~ 2 Гб

Comment: Вы делаете выборку по `users.department`, а индексов я не вижу на это поле, ровно так же как и `join users on schedules.user_id = users.id` нет индекса на users.id

Comment: И еще `and events.date between '2022-09-01' and '2022-11-28'` индекс у вас `events_date_index (date)`. В поле date как записаны даты? Вот в таком формате '2022-09-01' или с датой и временем?

Comment: @SwaD `schedules_user_id_foreign ` внешний ключ указан. `date` является типом `date`, формат без времени.

Comment: @SwaD про `department` упустил, на самом деле есть такой индекс. `users_department_index (department)`

Comment: Индексы по отдельным полям - бессмысленны при нескольких условиях связывания/отбора. Нужны композитные индексы, в первую голову по users и events.

Comment: @Akina Не подскажете, какие именно индексы нужны?

Comment: А это зависит от точной структуры таблиц и статистики данных. Более того, по мере изменения массива данных набор оптимальных индексов может и изменяться..